# How to add constructor for and class which is extending an generic class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript, inheritance

I have a generic class in typescript as bellow:

```
export class Result<T> {
    public ErrorMessage: string;
    public Data: T;

    constructor() {
        this.ErrorMessage = '';
        this.Data = null;
    }
}
```

Then have another class which extends the first one:

```
export class ResultList<T> extends Result<T> {
    public TotalCount: number;

    // how to place constructor which calls the base constructor?
}
```

I need to have a constructor for the child class in this case "ResultList", How could i create this constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just declare it and have it call `super`:

```
export  class ResultList<T> extends Result<T> {
    public TotalCount: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.TotalCount = 0; // Or whatever
    }
}
```

If you want it to pass along its arguments, you can use rest and spread notation to do that:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.TotalCount = 0; // Or whatever
}
```

Note that the call to `super` must occur before any access to `this` is allowed.

Comment: Wow, what could I say, I'm ashamed that did not try such simple thing.

Comment: @EhsanErshadi: LOL Sometimes it's easier than you think. :-)